# Is it possible to add a CASE statement to an UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've attempted to perform a CASE within an UPDATE below;

```
UPDATE [table]
SET CASE WHEN ((order - 20.00) < 0) THEN 0 ELSE (order - 20.00) END
WHERE id = 1
```

But I'm having trouble making it execute. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What's the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say what field you want to set.

```
UPDATE [table] 
SET somefield = CASE WHEN order > 20.00 THEN (order - 20.00) ELSE 0 END 
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the value to a column.

Answer (score 1):

Close, you forgot to add the name of the column you want updating to your statement

```
UPDATE [table]
SET <name-of-column> = (CASE WHEN ((order - 20.00) < 0) THEN 0 ELSE (order - 20.00) END)
WHERE id = 1
```